# Copying and pasting specific rows into new sheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with data for hundreds of schools, organized by school code. I want to find specific schools (by school code), and copy those rows into a new sheet. Rather than find each school one and by one and copy and paste, I was wondering if there is some macro or program that can help me do this more quickly.

Comment: sort the table by that column and copy the rows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might be worth glancing at https://superuser.com/ which is another site in the stack exchange family of sites. As asked the question is likely going to be closed as off topic here as it is asking for an existing macro or program recommendation. Before re-asking the question please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).